# CSS elements won't line up

Tags: css, styles

I have just embedded a newsletter field and button into my website, the field sits nicely but the button is too low. I tried different styles but nothing seems to work.

http://www.pazzle.co.uk/

Just underneath the banner.

```
   <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://pazzle.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=7167bf73b26b7bd1298d4f925&amp;id=a48b73e435" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->

#mce-EMAIL {float:left;}
#mc-embedded-subscribe {}
/* MailChimp Form Embed Code - Slim - 08/17/2011 */
#mc_embed_signup form {display:block;   }
#mc_embed_signup h2 {font-weight:bold; padding:0; margin:15px 0; font-size:1.4em;}
#mc_embed_signup input {border:1px solid #999; -webkit-appearance:none;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=checkbox]{-webkit-appearance:checkbox;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=radio]{-webkit-appearance:radio;}
#mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both;  background-color: #aaa; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;  font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 28px;  padding:0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#777;}
#mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 11px;}
#mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}     
#mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display:inline; float:left;}

#mc_embed_signup input.email {display:block; padding: 5px 0;  text-indent: 8px; width: 120px !important; margin-left: 13px;margin-top: 5px; float:left;}
#mc_embed_signup input.button {display:block;   min-width: 50px; height: 28px; margin-top: 5px;}

#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {float:left; top:-1.4em; padding:0em .5em 0em .5em; overflow:hidden; width:90%;margin: 0 5%; clear: both;}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {margin:1em 0; padding:1em .5em .5em 0; font-weight:bold; float:left; top:-1.5em; z-index:1; width:80%;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {color:#529214; display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {display:block; float:none; width:auto; margin-left:1.05em; text-align:left; padding:.5em 0;}
#mc_embed_signup {float:left; height: 30px;}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post.

Comment: Where exactly you want it to be?

Comment: Thanks, Lewis. including the related CSS might be good also, so this post remains useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `float: left` to the `#mc_embed_signup .clear` div and the `#mc_embed_signup input.email` textbox

Comment: that has been applied, not much change. Thanks for trying.

Comment: It's stumped me, I never usually have a problem with CSS :/

Comment: oh wow, just started working... My browser was slow sorry dude. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Will do, need to wait 4 minutes though ??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here in the CSS:

`#mc_embed_signup .button` on line 1176 of stylesheets.css

Get rid of the `clear:both` from that class and it will get the submit button in line with the form field. From there you should be able to fix up the margin/positioning.

clear:both essentially prevents the element from ever being inline with any other element. It clears floats such that it can't be floated next to another element.

Comment: That CSS rule was installed with Zen Cart, if I mess with those it causes all sorts of problems. The issue is fixed now with a bit of pinpoint styling.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is exactly what you were talking about but I added #mc_embed_signup .clear { float: right;}. this will put the submit button into the form box and then you can get specific with alignment using postion:relative